# How to set the callbacks for Android Firebase Phone Authentication?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

Im kinda new to firebase and android then I saw this new feature in android the firebase phone Auth. I was looking at this doucumentation [Firebase Phone Auth](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/phone-auth#verification-callbacks) and I am confused on Implementing this mCallbacks .. can someone pls guide me ?

```
PhoneAuthProvider.getInstance().verifyPhoneNumber(
                        phoneNum,
                        60,
                        TimeUnit.SECONDS,
                        this,
                        mCallbacks
```

this confused me is I dont know what data type should I use to assign that callback. since there is no sample code I wish someone might able to guide me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this solved my problem.

```
submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String phoneNum = editText.getText().toString();
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, phoneNum, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                verifyPhone(phoneNum,mCallBacks);
            }

    });
```

I tried to make a method to handle the button clicked, I dont know why but it worked..

```
 public void verifyPhone(String phoneNumber, PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks mCallbacks){
            PhoneAuthProvider.getInstance().verifyPhoneNumber(
                    phoneNumber,        // Phone number to verify
                    60,                 // Timeout duration
                    TimeUnit.SECONDS,   // Unit of timeout
                    this,               // Activity (for callback binding)
                    mCallbacks);        // OnVerificationStateChangedCallbac
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use a `PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks()`. Like so:

```
    PhoneAuthProvider.getInstance().verifyPhoneNumber(
            phoneNumber,        // Phone number to verify
            60,                 // Timeout duration
            TimeUnit.SECONDS,   // Unit of timeout
            this,               // Activity (for callback binding)
            new PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks() {
                @Override
                public void onVerificationCompleted(PhoneAuthCredential phoneAuthCredential) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onVerificationFailed(FirebaseException e) {

                }
            });
```

Then you could just override the other [Verification callbacks](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/phone-auth#verification-callbacks) that you need.

Comment: It gives me an error of cannot resolve verifyphonenumber

Comment: Do u happen to have a sample code of android firebase phoneuth?

Comment: Also throwing the same error to me as well. Same code as above.

Comment: same error here too `no suitable method found for verifyPhoneNumber`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing "this" inside the verifyPhoneNumber(..) method, Try to pass Activityname.this

Answer (score 0):

The problem at TimeUnit.SECONDS in Method verifyPhoneNumber 
you must replace the import Class TimeUnit 
to 
**import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit**;